# remove action from woocommerce file

Tags: actions

i a have a woocommerce file "checkout-form.php". I want remove the following actions via functions.php

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

I used the following code in the functions.php but nothing happens:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout, 20);
```

i cant find the error. When i delete the "actions" manually in the woocommerce file it works. with the "remove_action function in the functions.php i have no effect.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to understand how hooks or more specifically how action hooks work. We use [`add_action( $name, $callback )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to register an action hook which takes a name and a callback function as a required parameter. And we use [`do_action( $name )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) to run those registered action hooks which has been registered using `add_action()`.

Now, if we want to remove an action hook or more precisely a registered action hook then we will use [`remove_action( $name, $callback )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) which takes the same parameter as `add_action()`. So, to remove an action you have to know not only the action name but also the callback function name. You should know that there can be multiple actions with the same action name.

**Example**

```
do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' ); // Executing action hooks

function op_enqueue_scripts() {
    // ...
}

function op_enqueue_google_fonts() {
    // ...
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'op_enqueue_scripts' ); // Register an action hook
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'op_enqueue_google_fonts' );  // Register another action hook
```

**Remove action hook**

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'op_enqueue_google_fonts' );  // Remove an action hook
```

Answer (score 0):

You have remove specific action using remove_action.

So you can find all actions related to this and remove using functions.

```
    function action_woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review(  ) { 
        // make action magic happen here... 
    }; 

    // add the action 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 10, 0 ); 

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review','action_woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review',10, 0 );

    function action_woocommerce_after_checkout_form( $wccm_after_checkout ) { 
        // make action magic happen here... 
    }; 

    // add the action 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 10, 1 )

  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 10, 1 );
```

IF need to show error log enable config.php on wp_debug with true.

Now you want's remove do_action() so please override "form-checkout.php" file copy from plugin and add in your theme and create directory with this path

> "woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php"

Comment: thx... but nothing happend... when i delete the actions manually from the file it works.. strange...

Comment: he asks about `do_action`, not `add_action`

Answer (score -1):

You have to override return blank function for specific action.

Try this:

```
function remove_woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review( ) { 
    // 
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'remove_woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 10, 0 ); 


function remove_woocommerce_after_checkout_form( ) { 
    // 
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'remove_woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 10, 1 )
```